# jQuery nested window load events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onload-event

I am automating a web page using jquery/js to navigate, click links, etc.

The following script is inserted into an `index.php` file so the script runs on every page in the website i.e. it runs on page X and page Y. I ran into a problem when I used nested `$(window).on("load", function(){...});` events.

Here is the script.

```js
$(window).on("load", function(){
        //if webpage is at X
        if(window.location == "http://localhost/ca/providence/index.php/editor/objects/ObjectEditor/Save/Screen35/object_id/"){
            //navigate to location Y
            var url = $("#nav_screen_43").attr("href");
            window.location = "http://localhost"+url;
            
            //alert once location Y is loaded
            $(window).on("load", function(){
                //does not execute
                alert("test");
            });
        }
});
```

The function inside of the second window load event does not execute. Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. Javascript from one page won't work on another one. The page execution ends when you load a new page using `window.location`. If you want code to execute after the page load, it needs to be placed in the new page. If you want it to execute before then put it before your if statement.  Either way you would never need to nest the window.load event

Comment: edit: my apologies, I did not specify I am inserting into a website index.php file. The script will run on every page of the website.

Comment: Ok but the execution will still end on page load. It won't pick up where it left off.

Comment: ohhh okay I think i understand. If there's a "program pointer" in javascript that points to the code being executed what you're saying is that once the program pointer reaches window.location = '...'; the web page is changed/refreshed so the program pointer is reset to the top of the script and never reaches the second $(window).on("load") function, correct?

Comment: yes. Everytime the page loads or refreshes, the script starts from the beginning.